# ASP.net CSS max-width not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, doctype

I have one page created with ASP.net as well as in normal HTML.

Issue is when I browse that page in IE10, all CSS property working fine but in case of IE8 max-width property not working.

One problem is when I put

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

before
    `<html>` 
tag it works fine with IE8 also but without it not working.

In ASP.net in master page I put `<!DOCTYPE html>` but when I run website it will remove that. So its not working in IE8.

Why ASP.net remove that from the page?

with `<!DOCTYPE html>` :

[image]

without `<!DOCTYPE html>` :

[image]

CSS for tile box

```
.tilebox {
    color: white;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 85px;
    margin: 5px;
    min-width: 180px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
   }
```

and for parent div:

```
#boxcontainer {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 740px;
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

for div with id #boxcontainer max-width is not working.

Comment: http://www.zeilenwechsel.de/it/articles/5/How-max-width-fails-in-IE8.html

Comment: @maku I already tried that but I can't give width in percentage. I have to make it auto for .tilebox because texts are dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

`max-width` is not a part of the CSS definition for IE8. I use a polyfill to make it work, specifically Scott Jehl's respond.js:

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

So you get CSS3, including media queries, to *work* in IE6 - IE8.

EDIT - You need the HTML5 doctype to make it work. so the `<!doctype HTML>` is required.

Comment: I have no problem with <!doctype HTML> but in asp.net it will remove that line when page load in browser.

Comment: You shouldn't. You'll have problems with any HTML that goes to the client after the .NET server finishes sending to the client. You're throwing the browser into quirks mode if you don't have a proper doctype. So you should expect having bad issues with displaying content.